# If statment : read the "else" before

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

Hi I need help with if statment , it allways jump to the else before check the condition!
My code:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context p1, Intent p2)
{
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(p2.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(p1, "Device is ON from Recever",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent starServiceIntent = new Intent(p1,MyService.class);
   p1 .startService(starServiceIntent);

    }   @Override
public void onReceive(Context p1, Intent p2)
{
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(p2.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(p1, "Device is ON from Recever",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent starServiceIntent = new Intent(p1,MyService.class);
   p1 .startService(starServiceIntent);

    } if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){

        SharedPreferences prefs = p1.getSharedPreferences("myPrefss", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(!prefs.contains(incomingNumber)){
            Toast.makeText(p1,"True",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy HH:mm");
            timeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Jerusalem"));
            String curTime = timeFormat.format(new Date());


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(incomingNumber, curTime);
            editor.commit();
            sendSMS(incomingNumber,p1);

        }else{
            getStored(p1,incomingNumber);
            Toast.makeText(p1,"False",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        }
```

//give me false first then true ,Even if the condition is met

Comment: If it's going to the else, the condition is false. Double check your data.

Comment: Gives me false then true but why give me false first!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening most likely because you have not stored any value in the `SharedPreferences` before accessing it and therefore, it is returning `false` in your case. For a better explanation, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45052538/5493999) by Kaze.